# Using websocket in Banking?

Tags: node.js, websocket, tornado, onlinebanking

Node.js and Tornado are excellent servers that can be both websockets and http servers, but, how about using them in Banking applications?

Of course, not for 24h, but they will be used for the time a bank will be opened, for example, for 8 hours.

Is that a good idea, or keeping the connection opened for 8 hours is so much?

Answer (score 1):

So long as you don't have network issues then keeping a websocket open for 8 hours isn't a problem.

You could also setup your code to reopen the websocket in the background if it dies.

Comment: so websocket doesent have a practical limit of being opened?

Comment: There is no practical time limit of keeping a websocket open so long as the network is reliable.

Comment: and how about the number of the number of connections? the physical one of course

Comment: I think you mean logical connections, not physical connections.  Physical connections are the wires that connect your network.  Logical connections, the server can easily handle hundreds of connections without any tweaks.  With some minor tweaks you can handle tens of thousands of connections on the server.

Comment: and this is  the problem, i want to study the use case of websocket, because the http header are avoided, so the bandwidth will be freed, http://www.websocket.org/img/poll-ws-compare.gif
so the headers will be only sent once, when the connection when will be opened/reopened

Comment: Yes, websockets require much less bandwidth over long running connections than polling does.

Comment: is that used in some banking systems or e-commerce plateforms? or they just use the old request, open the connection, response, close  the connection ?

Comment: I don't specifically know of banking systems or e-commerce systems that are using websockets.  You can see that most browsers support websockets at this point.  http://caniuse.com/#search=websockets

Comment: maybe they fear it right now, maybe it is if there will be no ACK in response?

Comment: You should use socket.io.  It supports websockets and will also support fallback mechanisms like polling for when websockets are not working. https://www.npmjs.org/package/socket.io

Comment: in Tornado, there is https://github.com/MrJoes/tornadio2 and it seems that using it with e-commerce is risky, since no banking solution 'dare' adopting it